# Selenium - How to automatically Download PDF Files of Web Page if there is no Download Button?

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, pdf, browser-automation

1.) I'am trying to Download the Article PDF Files from multiple web pages to a local folder on the computer. But there is now "Download PDF" button on the web pages. What would be the Quickest and Best way to do this with Selenium ?

2.) One way I have thought of is to use the Keyboard Keys for Print, "Control"- "P", but inside Selenium, none of the Keyboard Keys are working when i run the program. The Code is below,

```
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_binary  # Adds chromedriver binary to path
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window() # Makes Full Screen of the Window Browser
time.sleep(4)

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/news/why-warren-buffett-doesnt-buy 152303112.html'                                                                           
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)

a = ActionChains(driver)
a.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('P').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

Comment: The question is not really clear to me, I do not see `Download PDF` button at this URL `https://finance.yahoo.com/`. I don't really see `Article PDF Files` anywhere

Comment: that example is just saving the home page as pdf.  But you can save it as a PDF, if you hit Print, than save as, it will save that home page as pdf.

Comment: i have edited it and replaced it with article link.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using `ChromeOptions()` and have a setting id, origin etc.

Also you can give `savefile.default_directory` to save the PDF file.

**Code:**

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
import json

Options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
settings = {
       "recentDestinations": [{
            "id": "Save as PDF",
            "origin": "local",
            "account": "",
        }],
        "selectedDestinationId": "Save as PDF",
        "version": 2
    }
prefs = {'printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState': json.dumps(settings), 'savefile.default_directory': 'C:\\Users\\****\\path\\'}
Options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
Options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')
driver_path = r'C:\\Users\\***\\***\\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=Options, executable_path=driver_path)

driver.maximize_window() # Makes Full Screen of the Window Browser
time.sleep(4)

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)

driver.execute_script('window.print();')
```

**Output:**

You should see a PDF file in the directory like this:

[image: PDF]

**Update:**

```
driver_path = r'C:\\Users\\***\***\\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=Options, executable_path=driver_path)
```

Comment: Thanks, but i'm getting 2 errors below when i run this, "  FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified", and "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home"                             "

Comment: and for the second error message that dealth with path, i believe maybe my selenium is adding to binary path, in the code above i put the import for it , "import chromedriver_binary"

Comment: If you were able to launch the browser with `driver = webdriver.Chrome()` command that you'd shared with us in the question. I would say use the same code for driver initialisation just keep options though, `driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=Options)`

Comment: yes, i kept "driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=Options)". But i still get those 2 Errors.

Comment: you will have to download `chromdriver` first from here https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/ and then put that inside a folder and use it like `driver_path = r'C:\\Users\\panabh02\\***\\Automation\\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=Options, executable_path=driver_path)`  see above update section for formatting.